# Search for tracking techniques

Tags: classification, image-processing, kalman-filter

I have an image with scatter points. Check the following figures. We can see a line and a sin function in the images, which are corrupted by noises. The tracks of the straight line and the sin function are broken. My aim is to connect these track and reconstruct the possible clean tracks from these observed information. I believe this should belong to a tracking problem, or maybe a 2D image tracking problem. Could anyone know something about these types of problems? Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a RANSAC approach for the line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus

Take two random points in the image and count the number of points in the line defined by these two points. After some iterations, you will find the best line i.e. the line that explains the most points.

For the sin function, you could do the same trick but I don't know how to find the parameters (offset, amplitude, frequency, phase) that fit exactly some points.

Comment: This looks quite good. Let me have a try. It seems this algorithm is not a very common one as I cannot find a function in matlab.